# change event is not firing

Tags: angular, angular9

I have a scenario where the textbox might change but not resulting from user input and I need to detect this change. Input defined as following:

```
<input type="text" (change)="onChange($event)" >
```

And in .ts I have the onChange method:

```
onChange(event:any){
  // something todo here
}
```

From what I understand, that should work in Angular 9, but the event is not firing. What am I missing?

Comment: The real question is, what is causing the change?

Comment: Might be user input or click on autocomplete option

Comment: In that case, (input) and/or (change) should capture most events. However, it might be better to not use an event handler at all but instead use a reactive form input.

Comment: In my case I do have reactive input but I need to notify other controls when text is changed

Answer (score 2):

**You can try these ways ..**

In **angular**  you can do like this: **`<input type="text" (keyup)="myFunction(this)">`** you can use **`(keyup)="yourFunction()"`** event.

**CASE 1**

You can use **`onkeyup`** event

```js
function myFunction(e) {
  console.clear();
  console.log(e.value);
}
```

```html
<form>
   <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
   <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" onkeyup="myFunction(this)"><br>
</form>
```

**CASE 2**

You can use **`oninput`** event

```js
function myFunction(e) {
  console.clear();
  console.log(e.value);
}
```

```html
<form>
   <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
   <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" oninput="myFunction(this)"><br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" (keyup)="onChange($event)" >
```

Use keyUp event for input element.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use input event as

```
<input type="text" (input)="onChange($event)" >
```

and it will work with you

Comment: That's what I was about to say. The reason: `The change event is fired for <input>, <select>, and <textarea> elements when an alteration to the element's value is committed by the user. Unlike the input event, the change event is not necessarily fired for each alteration to an element's value.` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event

Answer (score 0):

**the issue**

Changing the value programatically does not trigger the `change` event.

**emit your own event**

You can create your own `Event` using the [Event API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event). You will need access to the node you are binding the Event to ( you can use [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild))

See a live example in [this stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zvvns7).

*app.component.ts*

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  value = '';
  @ViewChild('input') input;
  onChange(event:any){
    alert('change event triggered');

  }
  changeValue() {
    this.value = 'Value set';
    // also trigger an event on the input.
    let event = new Event('change');
    this.input.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(event);
  }
}
```

*app.component.html*

```
<input #input type="text" (change)="onChange($event)" [value]='value'>
<button (click)='changeValue()'>Change</button>;
```

**or**

Or you can do it another way and run the code in the `onChange` method directly after programatically changing the value. Note that you may need to refactor your code in order not to rely on an emitted `$event`.